# Fixing grub.cfg

Tags: grub2

I had problems for dual boot windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I solved my Windows problem, but I can't boot Ubuntu from Hard Disk. When I run from Super GRUB2 and use the recovered GRUB cfg file option the boot don’t work, only work when I select the first option: found any OS.

Is there anything wrong in my Ubuntu Installation grub files for dual boot (both OS) ?
I would like to know your expert opinion before run "grub-install /dev/hda"

=========
This is and image of my Partitions (I have only 1 hard Disk)

```
tomas@tomas-HP-Compaq-CQ5000:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for tomas: 

Disco /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
255 cabezas, 63 sectores/pista, 77825 cilindros, 1250263728 sectores en total
Unidades = sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico / físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificador del disco: 0x7fff8ad0

Dispositivo Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   568414207   284103680    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       568416254  1227589631   329586689    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda4      1227589632  1250260991    11335680    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       568416256  1164101631   297842688    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6      1164103680  1223911423    29903872   83  Linux
/dev/sda7      1223921664  1227589631     1833984   82  Linux swap / Solaris

========
```

and this is the grub.cfg :

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos6)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 21745c1b-4a7d-4a6b-afd3-3a956f32f007
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd0,msdos6)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 21745c1b-4a7d-4a6b-afd3-3a956f32f007
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=es_CO
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "${linux_gfx_mode}" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu, con Linux 3.11.0-17-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 21745c1b-4a7d-4a6b-afd3-3a956f32f007
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-17-generic root=UUID=21745c1b-4a7d-4a6b-afd3-3a956f32f007 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-17-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-17-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 21745c1b-4a7d-4a6b-afd3-3a956f32f007
    echo    'Cargando Linux 3.11.0-17-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-17-generic root=UUID=21745c1b-4a7d-4a6b-afd3-3a956f32f007 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Cargando el disco RAM inicial...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-17-generic
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 21745c1b-4a7d-4a6b-afd3-3a956f32f007
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 21745c1b-4a7d-4a6b-afd3-3a956f32f007
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 089C91B49C919D2E
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry "Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda4)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,msdos4)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9074E29174E278FC
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy and quick fix: Download the Boot Repair ISO, burn that to a CD, run the automated Boot Repair program. It will take care of everything else-

```
Download link: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
```

Comment: Well, Due an this error reported by Boot Repair "FlexNet detectado...." i deleted the sector 1 - 63 with the comand sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=62 seek=1 and reran the program BootRepair and record the log in http://paste.ubuntu.com/7030573/ but the boot didnt work (only boot directly Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and dont show the other options of menu). Please tel me whats wrong ? thanks